# Django: constructing dyanamic query

Tags: django

i have a table **Genre** having values Drana, Thriller, Sci-fi, etc under "name" column. and another table **Movie**.
In Movie table genre is ManyTOManyField for Genre table

Scenario

```
movie_1 = {D,S, T}
movie_2 = {S,T}
movie_3 = {D}
movie_4 = {D, T}
```

D: Drama, S: Sci-Fi, T: Thriller

case 1:
Let say user choses D and T (which are checkbox options)

```
all D movies : movie_1, movie_3, movie_4  ---(a)
all T movies : movie_1, movie_2, movie_4  ---(b)
```

when user selects those options :
i want to show  movie_1, movie_2, movie_3, movie_4 which is a **intersection** of both (a) and (b)
for above case following query can be done like:

```
        qs_d = Genre.objects.get(name="Drama")
        qs_t = Genre.objects.get(name="Thriller")
        m_d = Movies.objects.filter( Q(gen__id=qs_d.id) | Q(gen__id=qs_t.id)).distinct()
        for movie_name in m_d:
            print movie_name
```

in above queries i have hard-coded the genre "Drama" and "Thriller" (for explanation) , but
I'll get the movie genre in a list like {"Drama", "Comedy" , "Thriller"} depending upon the number of options user choses  , in that case how can i construct the query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`|` is the `__or__` function, or you can use the `operator.or_` [function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions).

So you could do something like this:

```
from operator import or_
#Uncomment for Python3
#from functools import reduce
...
qs = [Q(gen__id=Genre.objects.get(name=name).id) for name in names]
m_d = Movies.objects.filter(reduce(or_, qs)).distinct()
```

That should do what you're looking for. I'm not terribly familiar with Django queries so there may be a better way. Of course you could combine it with something like:

```
m_d = Movies.objects.filter(reduce(or_, (Q(gen__id=Genre.objects.get(name=name).id) for name in names))).distinct()
```

Comment: undefined variable or ?

Comment: Presumably you have some `names` iterable, e.g. `names = ["Drama", "Thriller", "Comedy"]`

Comment: is the syntax for is correct, shouldn't be like or_(a,b). how can i import or_?

Comment: See the first line: `from operator import or_`. You might want to check out the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) for reduce, if the syntax confuses you. Have you tried this code? Is it giving you an error? If so, what is the (full) error?

Comment: after fixing or_ import it is giving Error in  Movies query: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'Genre' and 'Genre'

Comment: Whoops - missing the Q part. Fixed.